# Get the average of the cells whose neighboring cells have a certain value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

Hi! I made the above table and I want to get the average of all the Margin cells whose equivalent supplier is A. I've tried AVERAGEIF but it didn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: " I've tried AVERAGEIF but it didn't work." What have you tried, what was the result, what did you expect as a result?

Comment: @P.b Average Margin Row if Supplier is A. The error was #TRANSACTION (my Excel is in portuguese, so I'm not sure what's the english term. I expected it to give me the average of the margin rows whose neighboring cell in the Supplier column is A. I managed to to this with Pivot Tablets, but I'll still need to know this for another thing I'm planning to do.

Comment: So, can you reproduce your error with some sample data and post that in your question? This can help post your data: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: You appear to have your data stored as Table. Than add a column to the table and reference `=AVERAGEIF([Supplier],[@Supplier],[Margin])`

Comment: You can always test your condition before making it part of a SUMIF, AF, AVERAGEIF, etc.  Let's assume the suppliers are in A2:A14. Go to a blank area of your spreadsheet and type `=A2:A14` and make sure you get a matching column of A's and B's.  Then make that formula `=A2:A14="A"` and check if you are getting a column of proper TRUEs and FALSEs.  THEN we move up to `=AVERAGEIF(A2:A14,"A",B2:B14)` and see what we get.  If that works, the replace `"A"` with a cell reference if needed.  You've now isolated each step, leaving no mystery about what isn't working as expected.

Comment: And further to P.b's point, let's say this is in a table named "SupplierStats", then you could replace my A2:A14 above with `SupplierStats[Supplier]` and my B2:B14 with  `SupplierStats[Margin]`.  You'd start with your test cell being `=SupplierStats[Supplier]`.  If that works, then change it to `=SupplierStats[Supplier]="A"` and if that works, then to `=AVERAGEIF(SupplierStats[Supplier],"A",SupplierStats[Margin])`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(F2="","", AVERAGEIF(TB[Supplier], F2,TB[Margin]))
```

Where the table is named as: `TB`, then expand down the formula. Here the screenshot:

[image: sample excel file]

The list of suppliers is obtained as follow:

```
=UNIQUE(TB[Supplier])
```